# reading tab-delimited file with text using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a txt file with lots of text data and `sep = " "` is not working because the second column is all strings.

Data structure:

```
sentence_index  sentence
1   The Rock is destined to be the 21st Century 's new `` Conan '' and that he 's going to make a splash even greater than Arnold Schwarzenegger , Jean-Claud Van Damme or Steven Segal .
2   The gorgeously elaborate continuation of `` The Lord of the Rings '' trilogy is so huge that a column of words can not adequately describe co-writer\/director Peter Jackson 's expanded vision of J.R.R. Tolkien 's Middle-earth .
3   Effective but too-tepid biopic
```

The code I used:

```
sentences = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep=" ",error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the data?

Comment: Please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all Python related questions.

Comment: Anyway, what doesn't work? What do you mean "the second column is all strings?" You say the delimiter is a tab, but you are passing a space as the delimiter...

Comment: The `sep` you want is `\t`